# How to use Berkshelf to manage Organization repo?

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant, berkshelf

I'm a huge fan of Berkshelf and I've released few community cookbooks using it and its awesome.

Now, I'm starting a new chef project and I went ahead with Berkshelf for this too.

But I'm finding some confusions/difficulties using it for the project.

Following is in the Berksfile:

```
site :opscode

cookbook 'mediawiki', github: 'millisami/chef-mediawiki'
cookbook 'sp-mediawiki', path: 'site-cookbooks/sp-mediawiki'
```

I've generated my application cookbook inside the `site-cookbooks` folder.

When I do `berks install`, it errors out:

```
An error occurred while reading the Berksfile: no metadata.rb or metadata.json found at \
/Users/millisami/Code/chef-sp/site-cookbooks/sp-mediawiki
```

Now I'm wondering where do I generate my application `sp-mediawiki` cookbook?

If just create a new one `berks cookbook sp-mediawiki`, it will be similar to the library cookbook.

This sort of flow is perfectly done using `librarian-chef` which I am using on another project.

So, I'm trying to put a line that:

1. Berkshelf is good to develop individual cookbooks
2. Librarian-chef is good to manage the top-level orchestration

Am I right/wrong? How you folks use Berkshelf to manage your Org's chef-repo?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? It's okay to answer your own question. Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 3):

As I said in my response on GitHub:

If you have a `Berksfile` at the top of your `chef-repo`, you can you Berkshelf to manage all your cookbook dependencies for you.

For example, let's say I'm writing an application cookbook that depends on the apache2 cookbook. I would add to my `Berksfile`:

```
site :opscode

cookbook 'apache2', '~> x.x.x' # optional version constraint
```

And run the `berks install` command to install this cookbook. Because it's a library, it's installed on your machine "somewhere" and you shouldn't bother finding it. Now, you generate your application-cookbook (let's call it `my-apache2`):

```
$ berks cookbook my-apache2
```

And this will create the skeleton for you. Then you can add `apache2` as a dependency on this new cookbook in the `metadata.rb`:

```
name 'my-apache2'
# suppressed
version '1.0.0'

depends 'apache2'
```

And your directory structure looks like:

```
chef-repo
  |  Berksfile
  |_ cookbooks
    |_ my-apache2
```

Notice the `apache` cookbook is not there. The library cookbooks all live in `~/.berkshelf/cookbooks`, but you shouldn't worry about that. They are automatically pulled in and added to your path for you.

If another teammate wants to use your chef-repo, simply have them run `berks install` and all the necessary dependencies will be installed on their machine as well.

When you run commands like `berks upload`, Berkshelf will automatically find and resolve all the necessary cookbooks for you.

Does this make sense?

Comment: I know this question and answer are now almost two years old, but I'm still unclear how to use Berkshelf with an *organization* repo. You use an application cookbook as an example in your answer but it's not obvious to me how that applies to this question (particularly for Chef Zero). Does Berkshelf require a cookbook? Is there no way to create an organization repo that doesn't contain any cookbooks (directly) itself?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this got answered here: https://github.com/RiotGames/berkshelf/issues/535